# phpstorm looking for ssh key in wrong directory

Tags: git, ssh, push, phpstorm, ssh-keys

I have started using phpSorm and git integration to commit my changes.

Everything works fine with windows cmd when running the commands.
When pushing I am asked to enter ssh key for 'c/Users/safireo/.ssh/id_rsa'.
Which I do and it works.

However, when trying with phpStom, I get the following error :

> cannot spawn C:\Users\safireo\AppData\Local\Temp\git-ssh-0.bat: No
>   such file or directory unable to fork

I am still able to add and commit through phpstorm and push with cmd.

The path for the ssh key seem to be different. How can I tell phpStorm to look in the right location ?

Comment: I assume you have redefined the path to the SSH Key in the Server settings box? Is the path to the key inside the scope of the project local folders?

Comment: well, I guess finding where this option is would solve my problem. However I can find a path for git, I can't find where to indicate my ssh key path. Can I ask you in which menu you set this up?

Comment: on the remote host tab click the "..." icon which loads the remote connection screen, where you put in the SFTP password etc, choose auth type = SSH and a input box will appear underneath which has the location of the local SSHKey file. That should be in the project scope,

Comment: PHPStorm does have a mental number of settings and options, it takes some time to familiarise youself with them

Comment: so I actually also figured out I had to activate the remote host plugin to have access to this window, which I found, thanks ! https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/remote-host-tool-window.html But now, how to configure a sftp connexion with gitlab ? my gitlab address is git@gitlab.com:myname/myproject.git and whatever part of this I put in the sftp host, it's not working.

Comment: ok, so I actually put for sftp parameters, the parameters of my own remote server. Works nice, I'm connecting. But phpstorm still looks for an ssh key in the wrong folder when trying to push git commits...

Comment: Well, so the actual error is cannot spawn C:\Users\safireo\AppData\Local\Temp\git-ssh-0.bat: No such file or directory unable to fork. What is it trying to do? Maybe it's not a ssh issue ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help much with git commits via phpstorm :-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this problem with PhpStorm on Windows.

Everything was working from Git Bash, but not from PhpStorm.

Turns out that PhpStorm was using cmd.exe as it's terminal and Git was not working so well from cmd. To fix, we found in settings:

```
File > Settings > Tools > Terminal
```

and changed the "Shell path" to be the same as Git Bash, in our case:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

PhpStorm required a restart, but then all started working!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when using git between phpStorm and Pantheon.

My solution is that phpStorm is not run as administrator..

You will see the `git-ssh-0.bat` file actually exists in the temp folder.